# Shell command to see the HTTP headers

Tags: linux, shell, http-headers

Is there a shell command to see the headers of a HTTP request?

For example, I would like to know what the headers retrieved from `www.example.com/test.php` are

How can I do this?

Answer (score 53):

In order to retrieve only the header, give this a try:

```
curl -I http://www.example.com/test.php
```

From the `man` page:

> -I/--head
> (HTTP/FTP/FILE) Fetch the HTTP-header only! HTTP-servers feature
> the command HEAD which this uses to get nothing but  the  header
> of  a  document.  When used on a FTP or FILE file, curl displays
> the file size and last modification time only.

Comment: Also, `-D <file>` will save the headers to a file.

Answer (score 11):

Use wget for instance

```
wget -O - -o /dev/null --save-headers www.example.com/test.php
```

Comment: yes, but i don't want to save the page on my pc.....i only want to see the headers

Comment: You won't save it with this command

Comment: Yup, you're [just filling `/dev/null`](http://serverfault.com/q/232201/51929) :p `-O -` writes the headers to the stdout ("the console")

Comment: Command outputs headers *and* full page to stdout. (Ubuntu 16.04, wget 1.17.1)

Answer (score 8):

You can do that with curl:

```
curl -i 'http://example.com/'
```

Result:

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: http://www.iana.org/domains/example/
Server: BigIP
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
```

(for some reason, IANA decided to redirect example.com, result: no body)

[curls manual page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) about the `-i` option:

> -i/--include
>
> (HTTP) Include the HTTP-header in the output. The
>   HTTP-header includes things like
>   server-name, date of the document,
>   HTTP-version and more...

Answer (score 6):

Or you can use `HEAD http://www.example.com`.
The result is very similar to that produced by `curl -i 'http://example.com/'` although it seems to return more headers.

```
200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Sun, 20 Mar 2011 19:08:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Content-Length: 2945
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Last-Modified: Wed, 09 Feb 2011 17:13:15 GMT
Client-Date: Sun, 20 Mar 2011 19:09:08 GMT
Client-Peer: 192.0.32.8:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can see them with [curl](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2006/10/06/check-server-http-headers-with-curl/).

Answer (score 3):

Use `curl --include` to include the response-headers in the top of the response-body.

or `curl --verbose` to see it all including SSL certificate exchanging the handshake (plus other debug information)

if the request itself and neither the response-body are not of you concern, just use `curl --head`

for example `curl --head --no-check-certificate --url "https://example.com"`.

You can download gnu `curl` already pre-compiled for the most platforms.
curl is quite the useful too, especially if you would like to pipe or redirect the result inside a script.

*<sub>for example: https://superuser.com/a/1007898/429721</sub>